# Fixed y axis values on ApexCharts React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, charts, apexcharts

I'm trying to represent in a real timeline chart the input from a user's microphone in hertz (corresponding to each musical note from the second octave to the 6th). I'm trying to achieve something like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2cKU.png)

Right now I got: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dbVq.png). If I use the formatter function I get: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWqF5.png).

My problem is that I need to replace the hertz value for the octave scale (A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2 and so on) on the Y-axis.

My config:

```
 const initialOptions = {
    chart: {
      id: "realtime",
      height: 350,
      type: "line",
      animations: {
        enabled: true,
        easing: "linear",
        dynamicAnimation: {
          speed: 20,
        },
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        type: "x",
        autoScaleYaxis: true,
        zoomedArea: {
          fill: {
            color: "#90CAF9",
            opacity: 0.4,
          },
          stroke: {
            color: "#0D47A1",
            opacity: 0.4,
            width: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: "smooth",
      width: 0.99,
      opacity: 1,
    },
    markers: {
      size: 0,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      offsetX: 0,
      enabled: true,
    },
    xaxis: {
      show: true,
      categories: [0],
      tickAmount: 10, // optional tickAmount value
    },
  };
```

And I have tried updating the options on a useEffect like this:

```
 yaxis: {
          tickAmount: 1,
          labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function (val, index) {
              return currentNote; // This prints the same output on each line of the Y axis as in picture 2
            },
          },
        },
```

I've been stuck on this for days now and I'm not sure if I should move on to another library. Any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: It might help getting the answer if you tried explaining the problem in non-music terms.

If I understand the problem correctly, you should fix the data that are you passing to the library.

Comment: Imagine you have a piano with all the keys, every time you talk or sing your voice produces a sound that could more or so match one of the keys. I need to have all the piano keys in the y axis, so when I capture the audio from a microphone I can compare with each key and show the user in what key they are singing (to see if the are in pitch for example). So my yaxis should have every note in the piano.